# Get last selected item of a ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need to get the last selected item of a ListView which is in MultipleSelectionMode in JavaFX. My code is below but it does not give me the last selected item. It seems to give a random item from the selected items.

```
addDocumentPagesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<PageFile>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends PageFile> change) {
            while (change.next()) {

                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    List <? extends PageFile> l = change.getAddedSubList();
                    Object o = l.get(l.size() - 1);                        
                    PageFile pf = (PageFile) o;
                    System.out.println("Showing pdf file: " + pf.getFile().getName());
                 }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [`selectedItemProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty%28%29) which always points to the last selected item:

> The selected item property is most commonly used when the selection model is set to be single selection, but is equally applicable when in multiple selection mode. When in this mode, ***the selected item will always represent the last selection made***.

Comment: Thank you. This is correct if I want the last selected item.

I should have been more specific, I also want to get the last selected item after a item in a multiple selection has been unselected. I was hoping that getAddedSubList() or getList() would keep the selections in the order they were added, but i'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: By last you mean last in the list order or the last item the user clicked on?

Comment: If the latter, you can still use the that property to keep track of each selection but there may be an easier way.

Comment: I have a solution, the only problem is that when making a multiple selection two event that are marked as change.wasAdded() are called for each multiple selection, but other wise it works. The code is

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow and I am having trouble adding the code to the comment. The comment was too long and I haven't worked out how to format the code properly.

Comment: You can use pastebin and post the link to the code. But if you want to keep a track of selected items you may use the Stack. It supports the removing of arbitrary element so if you unselect arbitrary item. And the top of the Stack will always point to the last selected item.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works, the only problem is that when making a multiple selection two events that are marked as `change.wasAdded()` are called for each multiple selection.

```
if (change.wasAdded()) {
    List<? extends PageFile> l = change.getList();
    Object o = l.get(l.size() - 1);
    if (o != null) {
        PageFile pf = (PageFile) o;
        System.out.println("Showing pdf file: " + pf.getFile().getName());
    }
} else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
    List<? extends PageFile> l = change.getList();
    Object o = l.get(l.size() - 1);
    if (o != null) {
        PageFile pf = (PageFile) o;
        System.out.println("Showing pdf file: " + pf.getFile().getName()); 
    }
}
```